# How do I make my python code into .app on macOS?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, py2app, python-3.9

I have tried to do this with py2app but my app opens and then closes immediately. The modules in my code are:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from pytube import YouTube, Playlist
import pafy
import glob
import os
import earthpy as et
```

Does this problem has something to do with py2app not including the modules causing the app to not work? If any one is able to help me turn my code into an app that would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Here is my code if you need it: https://github.com/TheLostProgrammer/Video_Downloader/blob/main/Video_Downloader.py

Comment: Run your app through the terminal and paste the error here.

Comment: Hi, I found out that earthpy was not being included. I have swapped it out for `from os import path` and it seems to work well.... I am facing 2 other problems which are: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65747739/my-mac-app-i-made-with-pyinstaller-opens-and-then-closes-immediately-but-then-re

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. One of my modules was not being imported so it was swapped out. I also moved over to pyinstaller.