# My mac app I made with pyinstaller opens and then closes immediately but then reopens 30 seconds later

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller

I have made a macOS app using pyinstaller... It works but when opening the app, it opens then closes immediately and then reopens 30 seconds later.

To create this app I typed this command:

```
pyinstaller -Fw --icon=AppIcon.icns Converter.py
```

These are the files that my app was created with:

[image]

Here is the code: https://github.com/TheLostProgrammer/Video_Downloader/blob/main/Video_Downloader.py

I don't know if it is a problem with the command but I am puzzled to why this is happening. Can someone please explain what has happened?

Comment: Did you try reading the PyInstaller documentation - there’s a section titled ‘when things go wrong’.

Comment: I don't see anything about the app closing and reopening...

Comment: I would suggest the same thing here as well, run the application from the console and then check it if gives any traceback, if it does, paste it here.

Comment: I didn't get any errors.....

Comment: Here is a video to show what is happening: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c83kv-Rw8DFW4s379_mFE2e3qbqlMAFl/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out after reading through the documentation that I typed in the command wrong. Here is the new command I used `pyinstaller -w --icon=AppIcon.icns VideoDownloader.py`. Works like a charm.

Comment: Please try to add a comment explaining what was the cause of the issue and how to new command fixes it :)